# Wait for function to finish

Tags: javascript

i have a function called opslaanMelding()

in this function i insert a div with some text and i WANT to let display none it after 3 secs.
i think an other function is refreshing the page so the time out doens't work

any idea to wait for this function to finish and then let him continue?

this is my code :

```
innerDiv.innerHTML = term;
innerDiv.className = 'className';
innerDiv.id = 'myId';
console.log(innerDiv.getWidth());
innerDiv.style.marginLeft =  width- 80 + "px"; 
innerDiv.style.marginTop = "7px";
$('header').insert({after: innerDiv})
setTimeout(function() {
   // display none after 3 secs
    window.document.getElementById('myId').style.display = 'none';
},3000);
```

Comment: Put all the continuation stuff in that `setTimeout` callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> any idea to wait for this function to finish and then let him continue

You can't prevent the function from returning for three seconds without locking up the UI of the browser (and/or getting a "slow script" error), which of course would prevent your content appearing and so not do what you want.

Instead, have your function accept a callback that it calls when the three seconds are up, and put whatever follows it into that callback rather than running it immediately.

E.g., instead of:

```
yourFunction();
doSomething();
doSomethingElse();
```

make it

```
yourFunction(function() {
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
});
```

...and modify your function as follows:

```
function yourFunction(callback) {   // **** Note the `callback` argument
    innerDiv.innerHTML = term;
    innerDiv.className = 'className';
    innerDiv.id = 'myId';
    console.log(innerDiv.getWidth());
    innerDiv.style.marginLeft =  width- 80 + "px"; 
    innerDiv.style.marginTop = "7px";
    $('header').insert({after: innerDiv})
    setTimeout(function() {
        // display none after 3 secs
        window.document.getElementById('myId').style.display = 'none';

        // *************** Do the callback
        callback();
    },3000);
}
```

Comment: Thx didn't know this isn't possible that way 
(just started programming in jquery / javascript )